# Would this be the correct way to add a timer switch to an existing fan with thermostat?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, timer

We have an existing 120V AC exhaust fan wired to simple inline attic fan style thermostat.  We would like to add a timer switch so the fan could be manually turned on as needed.

Would this be the correct way to add a timer switch?

[image]

This is the sort of timer switch we are looking to add: [12 hour timer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LBHB2IA)

Comment: Is this for a fan _in_ the attic, or is it for a repurposed attic-type fan?

Comment: It's a 300 CFM bathroom fan in the ceiling of a storage room that is vented out a side wall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is precisely correct. Though I prefer red tape, but that's a preference, not a requirement to go buy a roll. Nicer (IMHO) because you can easily mark switched hots whether they be black or white.

Comment: I like the idea of using red tape, definitely makes it more visible.  Thanks.